# How to set the type of Json schema?

Tags: java, json, type-conversion, jackson, jsonschema

I have a Json Schema (shown below) which is created by Jackson through the representing Json class.

```
"startDate" : {
  "type" : "number"
},
"endDate" : {
  "type" : "number"
},
```

But I want the type of the `startDate` and `endDate` to be String rather than number or Integer. Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you help us understand your context a little better? That schema was generated from object descriptions that you don't own?

Comment: Sure. I have a Pojo class which has 2 variables of XMLgregorianCalendar datatype and I generate the Json Schema using the Pojo class with the help of Jackson method -- generateJsonSchema(). The Output which I got was like the above mentioned (i.e The type of the startDate and endDate in the Json schema should be string). Instead It is NUMBER. Now I expect the output with the type of string. Certianly I dont want to change the variable's datatypein my POJO. Will it be possible in any condition?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to show your original Java objects to get more info.

For what it is worth, configurability of JSON schema generation in Jackson is bit limited; but if it was moved to a module, much more could be done, including adding whole lot of configurability. Contributions are always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me. Sure. For an instance to let you understand my issue, The following are the variables (4) in my POJO.

protected String empID; protected String empname; protected String designation; protected XMLGregorianCalendar doj;

and While converting the POJO to Json schema by Jackson, I get the  output as expected for all variables expect doj.

{
 ....
        "doj" : {
          "type" : "number"
        }
      }

Now I want to change this particular type to be changed from Number to String. Hope now I'm clear.

Comment: Hmmh. I don't know of a way that would work for sure; but there is 'SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS' -- enabling of which might help? Otherwise I was to suggest using '@JsonSerialize(as=String.class)', but that might break serialization.

Comment: @staxman now that it is a module, is this possible now? Thank you.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla I suggest you try to see. I don't know off-hand, JSON Schema Module itself has no maintainer at this point and will probably be deprecated as there are better external tools.